# Avoid code to be executed until a Listener gets called?

Tags: java, events, jframe, wait

I got a Main class and another Class which extends a jFrame, which holds directly a jTable in it. I kinda want to stop the code from executing until something happens (= the User presses Enter). I then want to get the values of the selected row from the table which I am holding in my other class MyJFrame. As for now, I am trying to achieve this about like that:

```
ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[ ] columns = new String[] {"h1", "h2", "h3" };

result.add(new String[]{ "some", "test", "values" });
result.add(new String[]{ "some", "test", "values" });

ArrayListTableModel model = new ArrayListTableModel(result, columns);

//waiting for enter...

MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame(model);
int row = frame.getActiveRow();
selectedData = result.get(row);
```

PS: I hope you understand my problem, I had some trouble explaining it...

Comment: it is called `Listeners` check which listeners you can add to `JTable`

Comment: yeaaah.. i also solved it with them, the problem is just that the other code after "waiting for enter" already gets executed and i am having problems to avoid this..

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov changed the subject. hope it's more clear now.

Comment: so execute that code in Listener handler

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov yeah but i will need this code any further in my main class after then..

Comment: I don't understand. Please, post SSCCE and more explanation on what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem.

Comment: 1) *"..extends a jFrame, ..I then want to get the values of the selected row from the table which I am holding in my other class MyJFrame"*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  One of those frames should probably be a modal dialog to solve the immediate problem.  2) Don't extend frame, just use an instance.  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..extends a jFrame, ..I then want to get the values of the selected row from the table which I am holding in my other class MyJFrame..

See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  One of those frames should probably be a modal dialog to solve the immediate problem.  The dialog will 'pause' the program while open.

For an example of 'waiting for reply', see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800621/logout-the-application-when-application-closes/13800686#13800686).

[image]

Comment: aah you are my hero! I hard a hard time to explain but cool that someone exactly could help me anyways. I try to post better questions hopefully next time. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  I suspected I knew the answer after seeing *"other class MyJFrame"*, being familiar with that problem.  ;)

Comment: hah! yea that's another point.. i knew it it's kinda messy, just didn't know where I was doing bad practice. I'd say: 2 Problems solved once :)