# how to implement UTF-8 format in Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, character-encoding, encode

In my Swing chat application i am having the send button, one text area, and a text field.

If I press Send button, I need to send the text from text field to text area. It is working fine in English but not in local language.

Please give some idea or some code that will help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you some code to show the problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (the form of code I posted in [answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800621/logout-the-application-when-application-closes/13800686#13800686)).

Comment: I put the code here..Please help me to get the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the internal character representation of String is UTF-16, so you don't need to worry once you have the string in your JVM.

The problem is probably the conversion between a sequence of characters that gets sent over the internet and a String object. When parsing a string you need to provide the encoding, e.g. when using `InputStreamReader`, you have to pass the `Charset` parameter:

> `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`
>   Create an InputStreamReader that uses the given charset.

The encoding has to be provided, because Java can't magically guess the encoding of a byte sequence.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is incorrect. The internal representation of Strings is UTF-16 in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your support.Will you please give a small example .This help me a lot to understand easy...

Comment: How to do the encoding and decoding in java ?

Comment: Use google, Luke! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8