# UTF-8 support issue to Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to implement UTF-8 format in Swing application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804113/how-to-implement-utf-8-format-in-swing-application)

In Swing application I have the send button, one text area and a text field.

If I press the send button, I need to send the text from text field to text area

It's working fine in English But not in the local language...

```
package package1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class AEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField tf;
    JTextArea area ;
    Border border;

    AEvent(){

        area = new JTextArea(200,200);
        area.setBounds(60,200,300,200);

        border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        area.setBorder(border);

        tf=new JTextField();
        tf.setBounds(60,70,150,20);

        Button b=new Button("click me");
        b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);

        b.addActionListener(this);

        add(b);
        add(tf);
        add(area);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setSize(600,600);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s = null;
        try {
            s = new String(tf.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        area.setText(s);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new AEvent();

    }
}
```

Please give some Idea or some code that will help me to solve this..

Comment: what is the example of line in local language? Try to work around with `JTextAre.setFont()`

Comment: This should work. I would also suspect some font problem as @NikolayKuznetsov indicates.

Comment: @UwePlonus: this *is* an exact duplicate. He even copied the useless repetition of dots.

Comment: @UwePlonus, it think he didn't post that time and topic was outdated. So he posts SSCCE now.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: but the other question does contain the same code. Enhancing a question is much preferred over creating a new one with the same problem. This one should be closed.

Comment: @Nikolay the other code is 90% the exact copy. So enhancing the other question would be sufficient.

Comment: @UwePlonus, how would some one attract community attention to a question created couple of days ago?

Comment: @Nikolay how does the community profit if we answer the same question again and again? If the question is new (with more focus on the problem) then the answers would be profitable for the community and the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This breaks if the the platform default encoding is not `utf-8`. `tf.getText().getBytes()` gives you the bytes in the platform default encoding. `new String(tf.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8")` will create a corrupt string if the actual encoding of the bytes is not `utf-8`.

try

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    area.setText(tf.getText());
}
```

Comment: I used area.setText(tf.getText()); . but doesn't work..It shows lot of square boxes in text box and ????????  in textarea.

Comment: If you look at the result of `tf.getText()` in the debugger, does the string look ok you do you just get `????????`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you are still not convinced of Phillipe's answer, here is a fully working code which demonstrates the good answer. I tried it with accented characters and it works just fine. If it breaks, please indicate how.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class AEvent implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField tf;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JFrame frame;

    protected void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        area = new JTextArea(30, 80);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setFocusable(false);
        tf = new JTextField();
        JButton b = new JButton("click me");
        b.addActionListener(this);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        frame.add(scrollPane, gbc);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        frame.add(tf, gbc);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        frame.add(b, gbc);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        tf.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.append(tf.getText() + "\n");
        tf.setText("");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AEvent().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this?

```
String s = null;
try {
    s = new String(tf.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
area.setText(s);
```

Why not just:

```
area.setText(tf.getText());
```

Comment: I used area.setText(tf.getText()); . bue doesn't work..

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do do your objective with a local language it worked fine for me. Can you please specify which local language are you considering and on what IDE are you working?

Comment: This is more a comment ;) [2]