# How would I execute a function before you close JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, windowlistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call a method when application closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800621/call-a-method-when-application-closes)

I want to call a method just before I close my java application using setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
I have tried WindowListener with windowClosed/windowsClosing and it doesn't work. 
  it looks something like this

```
public class exampleFrame JFrame implements{

public exampleFrame (){
    this.addWindowListener(new windowAction());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class windowAction implements WindowListener{

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.prinln("window closed")

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.prinln("window closing")
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like?

Comment: *"Can you do something like that?"* Yes, you can.

Comment: doesn't work as in nothing comes out. for example you put a System.out.println("windows close");...that message doesn't show so the function window close or windowsClosing is calling that. or unless i am doing it wrong.

Comment: this.addWindowListener(new windowAction());

Comment: First, use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` if using a `WindowListener` (as seen in the answer of the duplicate).

Comment: *"if u.."*  If you spell properly I might read your comments.  Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: sorry my english is bad lol

Comment: (from latest code) `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`  But if you choose to ignore the working code on the duplicate thread, as well as my explicit advice in comments, I don't think there is any chance of you solving this.  :(

Comment: oh it is cool then i will try my and figure it out

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame{
   public ExampleFrame(){

      // you can use WindowAdapter and implement only the methods you need
      addWindowListner(new WindowAdapter(){

           @Override
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent et) {
               System.out.println("Window closing");
           }
      }
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Try that and see it fail (for at least two reasons).